# Is it correct to use 'home based'?

Tags: word-usage, hyphens

In the following sentence, is it grammatically correct to use 'home based'? I wrote that sentence. I'd like to know whether the word 'home based' should be hyphenated or not. I think it doesn't need a hyphen in predicative use although, in attributive use, it is hyphenated.

> The education of our country should be home based during the Covid-19 pandemic.

Comment: You should tell us: 1. Did you write that sentence? Or where did you see it? 2. Why do you think it might not be correct?

Comment: I wrote that sentence. I'd like to know whether the word 'home based' should be hyphenated or not.

Comment: a hyphen wouldn't hurt, but its not essential.

Comment: I'm in favour of a hyphen.